# C free linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I need to know how to modify the free function to remove the first element of the list (last added). I must not interfere with the main function.
This is how the last element added to me remains in the list.

```
typedef struct TEmployee
{
    struct TEmployee *m_Next;
    struct TEmployee *m_Bak;
    char *m_Name;
} TEMPLOYEE;


TEMPLOYEE *newEmployee (const char *name, TEMPLOYEE *next)
{
    TEMPLOYEE *n = (TEMPLOYEE*) malloc(sizeof(*next));
    
    n->m_Name = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    strcpy(n->m_Name, name);
    n->m_Bak = NULL;
    
    n->m_Next = next;
    
    return n;
    
}


void freeList ( TEMPLOYEE *q )
{
    TEMPLOYEE *x = q;
    
    while( x != NULL)
    {
        TEMPLOYEE *tmp = x->m_Next;
        free(x);
        x = tmp;
    }
    free(x);
    x=NULL;
}
```

Comment: What does "I must not interfere with the main function" mean?

Comment: Above function is deleting all the nodes, also there will be a failure when calling `free(x)` after the loop. Do you want to free the first node alone or the most recently added node? It is not clear from your question.

Comment: I want to free everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the `freeList` method deletes all the elements in the linked list.

To just delete the first element of a linked list, the algorithm should be as follows:

1. Given the `head` as the input.
2. It could be possible that the `head` itself is `NULL` meaning the list is already empty, in that case we can simply return.
3. In the other case, we can simply set `head = head->m_Next`.
4. Now, since we also have previous pointers, we need to update the previous pointer for the current head, i.e. `head->m_Back = NULL`.

Please try to use the above algorithm and write the updated `freeList` method.

Comment: How can I implement this if I can't change the header of the freeList function

Comment: Because I pass a pointer to the first element of the list

Comment: As long as only a copy to the first element of the list is passed and nothing returned (i.e. `void`) function, it simply is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you pass the pointer to the first element *by value*.  If you want to modify the value of the head pointer, you need to pass it *by reference*, as in:

```
void freeList ( TEMPLOYEE **q )
{
    TEMPLOYEE *x = *q;
    
    while( x != NULL)
    {
        TEMPLOYEE *tmp = x->m_Next;
        free(x);
        x = tmp;
    }
    /* free(x); this is incorrect, tmp is already NULL when you
     * get out of the while loop
     * x=NULL;  // and this is nonsense, it's already NULL and you are not
     *          // using x anymore.
     */
    *q = NULL; /* this is what you lack, to assign NULL to the pointer. */
}
```

Later, you need to call `freelist()` as follows:

```
    freelist(&list_head);
```

to pass a reference of the pointer instead of the pointer's value.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot reliably be done without modifying the caller.

In it's basic form, you just have to free the node and trust that nobody uses it anymore:

```
void freeFirst ( TEMPLOYEE *q )
{
    if (q) {
        free(q->m_Name);
        free(q);
    }
}
```

Now to make this a bit more reliable, you should also modify the queue head node. This can be done by passing a double pointer to allow modification of the head node pointer:

```
void freeFirst ( TEMPLOYEE **q )
{
    TEMPLOYEE *x = *q;

    if (*q) {
        *q = (*q)->m_Next;
        free(*x->m_Name);
        free(*x);
    }
}
```

Now it's important that the caller is modified, instead of `freeList(list)` you would now need `freeList(&list)`.

Not that I have also freed the `m_Name` member, because otherwise you will leak the memory.

You should also use `strdup` instead of your combination of `malloc` of arbitrary length and `strcpy`, that could cause a buffer overflow.

Comment: I can't modify the header of the function, I noticed that I don't release the name variable. Isn't that my fault?